# What's the best way to implement a vertical timeline - iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, timeline

First of all, apologies if this question isn't meant here. I searched a lot but didn't find anything.

What is the best approach to create a vertical timeline kind of view?

I tried implementing via `UITableView` by alternating `cells` but that approach is very messy in terms of autolayouting (had to disbale autolayout and apply programtically when creating cell on alternate side), thereofre isn't working properly (getting stuck while scrolling). This is what I achieved:

[image]

I want to achieve something like this, which is also easily manageble:
[image]

**Please Suggest. Thanks!**

Answer (score 3):

I would have 1 cell row with two image views. One on the left, one on the right. I think this would be easier to use auto layout.

Then you can hide the image view and labels that shouldn't be used.

Comment: Dude, your answer is actually pretty smart :) Thanks :D But that would require me to create all items duplicate with double `IBOutlets` right? Will that be a nice thing to do?

Comment: I wouldn't call them duplicates, they're separate image views. Call one leftImageView, and the other rightImageView, or whatever you want. This shouldn't be a problem at all. Tableviews are very efficient.

Comment: I meant double double items. Not literal duplicates. Thanks for your answer Chris :)